# I don't know how to handle checked exception in method run properly in my case

Tags: java, multithreading

I have class Downloading that extends Thread. It has method run,

```
int attempt = 1;
String currentTry = destination + "/" + fileName;
while(Files.exists(Paths.get(currentTry))){
      currentTry = String.format(destination + "/(%s)" + fileName,attempt);
      attempt++;
}
fileName = currentTry;
try {
     Files.createFile(Paths.get(currentTry));
     OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(currentTry)),contentLength);
     InputStream is = source.openConnection().getInputStream();
     int info;
     while ((info = is.read()) != -1) {
             os.write(info);
             downloadedBytes++;
            }
     os.flush();
     os.close();
     is.close();
      } catch (IOException ex){
                
      }
}
```

I also have class DownloadingManager

```
private List<iDownloading> threads = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public void start(iDownloading downloading) throws IOException {
        threads.add(downloading);
        downloading.start();
    }
```

and, finally, class CommandAnalyzer.

```
public Object getResult(Object command) {
        if (command.equals("-status")){
            return downloadingsManager.getInfo();
        }
        String[] commandParts = ((String)command).split(",");

        if (commandParts.length == 2){
            if (!Files.exists(Paths.get(commandParts[1]).toAbsolutePath().normalize()) || !Files.isDirectory(Paths.get(commandParts[1]).toAbsolutePath().normalize())){
                return "can't perform command as second argument is not real directory";
            }
            try {
                downloadingsManager.start(new DownloadingWithProgressBar(commandParts[0], commandParts[1]));
                return "downloading started successfully";
            } catch (IOException ex){
                return "something went wrong. try again";
            }
        }
        else{
            return "unknown command";
        }
```

I want my method Run to throw IOException so it can be caught inside try-catch block in CommandAnalyzer. But i just can't do that. Neither i can print information about this exception inside try-catch in Downloading because my Downloading class doesn't have access to class that prints information, nor can i give any information about caught exception to class who manages all downloadings. Any suggestions what i can do in this situation?

I read about `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`, but i don't think it can help me, because its method uncaughtException() doesn't give me opportunity to throw this exception(i can throw unchecked exception, but logically i have to throw IOException).

I also thought about something like this: let my Downloading have field `IOException ioex`, and in `catch` block i create new instance of `IOException` to this field. Then i'll have to add method `GetIOException` to my iDownload interface(because DownloadingManager has List of interfaces), and in `Downloading manager` in method `start` just check if this field is null, if not - throw exception. it will surely work, but i know this is plain stupid because of SOLID.

Comment: It's in a different thread, which means a different stack of exception handlers, which means you can't do what you want.  You should look into using something like a CompleteableFuture to convey the results (possibly an exception) from the 'run' method to your getResult routine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in `getResult` **starts** the process of downloading but will then immediately continue and exit.

Hence, why you simply can't do this, and there's no simple language trick either.

Some ready alternatives:

- Along with passing the resource to download, pass an 'error handler' that the `DownloadManager` will invoke: *it* does try/catch (inside the thread!) and invokes your handler in the catch block. Such an error handler can take the shape of e.g. a `Consumer<Throwable>` possibly, or perhaps more likely `Consumer<IOException>`.
- Set up that uncaught exception handler. To make that work: In your actual download-with-progress-bar code, catch IOException and rethrow it as `throw new UncheckedIOException(e);` - this WILL get to the uncaught exception handler where you can catch it and do whatever you want with it. However, you can't throw `IOException` (or any other exception) from your `getResult` thread, because **it is already looong done and gone**.
- Wait. Your `getResult` method is free to fire up the download in a separate thread and then wait until it is done. This is in fact **the only way** to convey an exception given that a method rather obviously cannot throw exceptions after it has already finished running. However, if this is the plan, why.. start a thread in the first place? Might as well do the downloading from within getResult.
- Apply this principle further up the callstack. For example, maybe `getResult` should itself take a `Consumer<IOException>` which you then pass along to the downloader. The name `getResult` is bizarre. Why does a method named `getResult` do the following job: "Set up a download, start it on a different thread, return before it is completed, and return nothing (how could it - it cannot tell if it succeeded because you start it on another thread).